# Access, modify data in HI and LO in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips, cpu-registers

I need to store a binary number in a register and basically be able to access the first half and the second half whenever I want. how do i store a number in a register (or multiple registers) and still be able to shift left or right, and also accessing the number from both halfs.

Thanks Guys!

Comment: Please note that HI and LO are also names of special registers in MIPS. Using HI and LO as synonyms for high and low halfword of a register is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Say the number is in $t0.

```
andi $t1 $t0 0xFFFF #$t1 contains one half of $t0
lui  $t2 0xFFFF
and  $t1 $t0 $t2 #$t1 contains the other half of $t0
```